# .gitignore adding all files in folder recursively to white list?

Tags: git, gitignore

This looks like basic, thing but I just can't find any good examples. So I have a solution that contains bin folder with DLLs inside. I want them ALL to be pushed to the repo no matter what global .gitignore says.
So  should I write in local .gitignore

```
!/*.*
OR
/*.*
```

?

Comment: To `add ALL files` means to add them to the set of ignored files, or to add them to the git repository  (hence 'not ignore' them)?

Comment: I mean to ADD ALL files that I want to push. I want to override any eventual option already set in global gitignore. For example if I have bin dir in the project and it contains *.dll files then I want to include them too.
So I want to be able to push ALL files in my solution !
Such a trivial thing and so difficult to find :(

Comment: @leonbloy sorry it was confusing question . i have updated the post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `!/path/to/files/*.*` or `!/path/to/files/*` to the `.gitignore` file. You could tweak it further by specifying the extension of the `DLL`s by using `!/path/to/files/*.ext` to be more specific.

Hope that answers the question?

Comment: so adding .gitnore in root of my solution with !*.* should NOT ignore all files in my subfolders , right ?

Comment: sorry it was confusing question . i have updated the post

Answer (score 0):

To add files recursively, use `!/path/to/files/**/*.*`.  This will ensure that the contents of the directory `/path/to/files`, as well as any sub-directories, will be whitelisted.